# A group homomorphism from a simple group is injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, simple-groups, group-homomorphism

Let $G_1$ be a simple group, that is the only normal subgroups of $G_1$ are itself and the trivial subgroup. If $\phi : G_1 \rightarrow G_2$ is a group homomorphism, does that mean $\phi$ is injective? Could someone explain?

Comment: It does not mean that $\phi$ is injective.  Since the kernel of $\phi$ must be a normal subgroup, the kernel can only be trivial or $G_1$.  If the kernel is trivial, $\phi$ is injective.  Otherwise, if the kernel is $G_1$, then $\phi$ is the zero map and is not injective (unless $G_1$ is, itself, trivial).

Answer (score 7):

Looking at $\ker \phi\lhd G_1$ we note that $\phi$ is either injective or trivial.

Comment: Thank you so much Hagen. So if $kerϕ$= $G_1$, then  $ϕ$ is not injective, why cannot we have this case?

Comment: We can have this case. That is the case where $\phi$ is trivial that he refers to.

Answer (score 4):

First of all let's make an observation.

> **Oss:** Let $f:G \rightarrow H$ an homomorphism of groups. Then $\ker f$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

In fact if $k \in \ker f$ for all $g \in G$ we have that $f(gkg^{-1})=f(g)f(k)f(g^{-1})=f(g)f(g^{-1})=e$.
Then $g \ker f  \, g^{-1} \subset \ker f $ that implies $\ker f$ is normal in $G$

Now in your case $G$ is simple so $\ker f$ can only be $\{e\}$ or all $G$, so the homomorphism is injective or is the null one.