# Intersection of subgroups of given orders and normality

Tags: group-theory

Quite confused about how to solve this question..As it would have been easier to solve if the group was given to be cyclic, but no such case here

Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a group $G$ of orders $14$ and $21$ respectively. If $H \cap K \neq\{e\}$, here $e$ is the identity of the group $G$, then show that $H \cap K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: I guess "H int K" means $H \cap K$, is It?

Comment: This is not true. I suspect you have missed some information about the group $G$. For example, we can take $G=S_n$ for some $n$ (why?) and then $G$ has very few normal subgroups, and in particular none of order $7$.

Comment: YES its that only..No the question is complete.. I can share pic if possible

Comment: Maybe there's a typo? I can prove it if $H\cap K\ne\{e\}$ is changed to $H\cap K=\{e\}$.

Comment: It is true if $H$ and $K$ generate $G$.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. The issue/trick is that there is no information about the group $G$ so I can pick it to have very few normal subgroups.

For example, we can take $G=S_n$ for some $n\geq 7$ (why?). Then $G$ has very few normal subgroups (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/482889/10513)), and in particular none of order $7$ (why is $7$ relevant?).

For a concrete counter-example, take $H=\langle (1,2,\ldots,7)(8,\ldots,14)\rangle$ and $K=\langle (1,2,\ldots,7)(8,\ldots,21)\rangle$.

Comment: yes i have mentioned this thing in title that no information about G is given.. You may see it

Comment: @saurabh do you understand what my answer is saying?

Comment: Not actually... Quite confusing, Why are you taking G as symmetric group while no information is given about G..Also we are not disproving it..That we can do by taking counter example..As no information about G is given how  we gonna take G in Exam

Comment: Because no information is given about $G$ I can pick it to be whatever I want (picking $G$ is really just finding the counter-example). As every group embeds into some symmetric group, the situation in the question must occur in some symmetric group.

Comment: Hmm...maybe for a *true* counter-example you should find the $H$ and $K$. There are easy examples of groups with this property in $S_{21}$, but I'll let you find them (you just need to find some group which has two subgroups with the appropriate property. Combine with my answer to get the counter-example.

Comment: @user1729, to complete your counter-example, shouldn't you show that such $S_n$ has actually two subgroups as in the OP?

Comment: @Luca yes, see my comment immediately above yours! (Although you don't actually have to show that $S_n$ has two such subgroups, but that *some* group has! Then embed this into $S_n$.)

Comment: @user1729, oh I see! Yes, right.