# Is $G$ normal subgroup of $S_6$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G \subset S_6$ will be subgroup of permutation of a set $I_6=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ such that
$$\forall x \in I_6 :2|x \Longleftrightarrow 2|\sigma(x).$$

Is $G$ is normal subgroup of $S_6$?
I am a little confused, because I am not sure how it (construction of group $G$) 'works'.

Comment: I see that you've been here for over a year, so surely you know that you should avoid "no clue" questions like this. (Also, it is unclear what you mean by "it". Do you mean proving normality, or do you mean how the subgroup is defined?)

Comment: @PeterForeman This is permutation value for $x$. \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 &  \cdots  \\
    \sigma(1) & \sigma(2) & \cdots 
  \end{pmatrix}

Comment: If $s\in G$ then $s$ maps $A=\{1,3,5\}$ to $A$ and $s$ maps $B=\{2,4,6\}$ to $B$ so $s=s_As_B=s_Bs_A$ where $s_A$ is a permutation of $A$ and $s_B$ is a permutation of $B.$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482889/normal-subgroups-of-s-n-for-n-geq-5   . From my prior comment, $G$ has $3!^2=36$ members but $A_6$ has $6!/2=360$ members.

Comment: I notice that you addressed the second part of my comment, about what "it" is. However, your question is still a "no clue" question. You need to improve it.

Comment: Try conjugating by the first element you think of? Say, $(1,2)$?

Comment: @runway44 I know it's not in $G$. Conjugating by something that is already in $G$ wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: @runway44 Yes exactly, you want to conjugate something in  to get something not in  to prove it's not normal. But for that, you need to choose a conjugating element that is not in $G$.

Comment: Oh. Somehow I missed the word "by" in David's comments.

Comment: Aha. Yes, conjugating $(1,2)$ wouldn't do much good, true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subgroup $G$ (closure) is made of the permutations on $I_6:=E\sqcup O$ ("even and odd") which send "even-to-even" *and* (then) "odd-to-odd". Take an $\alpha\in S_6$ which sends *some* even to odd, but not *all* the even to the odd, say it "mixes up even and odd"; then $\alpha(E)$ is neither $E$ nor $O$. Accordingly, we can find a permutation $\sigma\in G$ which sends $\alpha(E)$ to a set distinct from $\alpha(E)$: for example, legitimate such $\alpha$'s and $\sigma$'s are all those such that:

$$\alpha(2)=\color{red}{1}, \space\space\space\alpha(4)=\color{blue}{4}, \space\space\space\alpha(6)=\color{green}{2}\tag 1$$

and

$$\sigma(\color{red}{1})\space\stackrel{odd-to-odd}{=}\space3, \space\space\space\space\sigma(\color{blue}{4})\space\stackrel{even-to-even}{=}\space2, \space\space\space\space\sigma(\color{green}{2})\space\stackrel{even-to-even}{=}\space4$$

So, by choosing "mixing up" $\alpha$'s ("exists..."), we have been able to build up $\sigma$'s ("exists...") such that:

$$\sigma(\alpha(E))=\{3,2,4\} \ne \{1,4,2\}=\alpha(E)=\alpha(\tau(E)), \space\forall \tau\in G \tag 2$$

We can read $(2)$ this way:

$$\exists\alpha\in S_6, \exists \sigma\in G\mid (\sigma\alpha)(E)\ne (\alpha\tau)(E), \space\forall \tau \in G \tag 3$$

whence:

$$\exists\alpha\in S_6, \exists \sigma\in G\mid \alpha^{-1}\sigma\alpha\ne \tau, \space\forall \tau \in G \tag 4$$

or equivalently:

$$\exists\alpha\in S_6, \exists \sigma\in G\mid \alpha^{-1}\sigma\alpha\notin G \tag 5$$

meaning $G\ntrianglelefteq S_6$.

Answer (score 1):

Take an element in $G$, for instance
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
1 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix}
$$
As a product of disjoint cycles it is the transposition $(24)$. Let's conjugate by $(12)$:
$$
(12)(24)(12)=(14)
$$
which does not belong to $G$, because it maps $4$ to $1$.

Counterexample found, the subgroup is not normal. By the way, I *knew* it isn't normal even before looking for the counterexample, because the only nontrivial normal subgroup of $S_6$ is $A_6$ (which is known to be a simple group) and certainly $G\ne A_6$, because $(123)\in A_6$, but $(123)\notin G$.