# If $n\geq 5$ prove that $A_n$ is the only nontrivial normal subgroup in $S_n$. But please don't use the fact $A_n$ is simple if $n\geq 6$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, simple-groups

I am reading "Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein.
The following problem is Problem 17 on p.81 in this book.

> Problem 17:
> If $n\geq 5$ prove that $A_n$ is the only nontrivial normal subgroup in $S_n$.

I was able to understand the following answer to this problem if I assume $A_6,A_7,A_8,\dots$ are all simple:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/482893/384082

There is no proof of the following fact before p.81 in this book:

> $A_6,A_7,A_8,\dots$ are all simple.

And the following problem (Problem 14) is on p.81:

> Problem 14:
> Prove that $A_5$ has no normal subgroups $N\neq (e), A_5$.

I solved Problem 14. But I had to use several facts the author didn't write before p.81.

Is there any solution which doesn't use the fact $A_6,A_7,A_8,\dots$ are all simple?

Or does the author expect the reader proves the fact $A_6,A_7,A_8,\dots$ are all simple?

Comment: Yes, see Lemma $2.4$ in K. Conrad's notes [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwio8-jfwYn2AhVDPuwKHarGCPEQFnoECDkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkconrad.math.uconn.edu%2Fblurbs%2Fgrouptheory%2FAnsimple.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0yq2vSRgLIJV1nS6ihyPcE). It doesn't use that $A_n$ is simple for $n\ge 5$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you very much for your link. I am not sure if I can understand the notes, but I will try to read the notes. Thank you.

Comment: I am sure you can understand the notes, and in particular Lemma 2.1 or 2.4. It is written in all detail and is very elementary.

Comment: @DietrichBurde As you said, K. Conrad's notes were written in all detail and were very elementary. And the notes were self-contained. I was able to understand Lemma 2.4.  Thank you very much!