# Find the number of group homomorphism between $A_5$ and $S_5$.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, group-homomorphism, simple-groups

The above question is based on this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3047830/number-of-homomorphisms-between-two-arbitrary-groups) to a similar question. I just want to apply what has been pointed out in that answer to this question.

So we are interested in number of homomorphisms $f:A_5 \to S_5$ (if any). 
Now following the ideas given in the linked answer, $A_5$ is simple, so it has to normal subgroups, viz $\{e\}$ and $A_5$.

If $f$ is a homomorphism then ker$f$ is a normal subgroup of $A_5$.

1. If ker$f$=$\{e\}$ , then $A_5/\{e\}\sim f(A_5)$, and so $f(A_5)$ is a subgroup of $S_5$ of order $60$.
2. If ker$f=A_5$, then $f$ is trivial.

Also we know that *"Any homomorphism from a simple group to any group is either trivial or injective."*

Now in the view of above argument what can I conclude? It seems to me that only I can conclude that any homomorphism is injective. But how to calculate how many are there?  Is it a valid approach or do we need a new approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Also we know that *"Any homomorphism from a simple group to any group is either trivial or injective."* $-$ You have shown that already in $(1)$ and $(2).$

Comment: I think $A_5$ is the only subgroup of $S_5$ of order $60.$ So in order to find the number of injective homomorphisms from $A_5$ to $S_5$ you need only to find the number of elements in $\text {Aut} (A_5) = \left |A_5/Z(A_5) \right| = |A_5| = 60,$ since $Z(A_5) = \{e \},$ where $Z(A_5)$ is the center of $A_5.$

Comment: For the proof of the above fact see here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/822096/543867

Comment: "If ker$f$=$\{e\}$ , then $A_5/\{e\}\sim f(A_5)$" What does "$\sim$" mean in this context?

Answer (score 7):

As you observed, the non-constant homomorphisms are injective. Because $A_5$ is the only subgroup of $S_5$ of order $60$ we are looking for automorphisms from $A_5$ to itself.

To each element $g\in S_5$ we get a conjugation automorphism $\phi_g(x)=gxg^{-1}$ for all $x\in A_5$. Because the centralizer of $A_5$ in $S_5$ is trivial, distinct choices of $g$ yield distinct automorphisms $\phi_g$.

**Claim.** Any automorphism $\phi$ of $A_5$ is of the form $\phi_g$ for some $g\in S_5$.

**Proof.** The group $A_5$ has five distinct Sylow $2$-subgroups. Namely
$$P_5=\{1,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$$
and its conjugates, each stabilizing a single element of $J_5:=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.
I will denote by $P_i$ the conjugate stabilizing $i\in J_5$.
Because $\phi$ is an automorphism it must permute these 5 groups. So there is
a permutation $\sigma\in S_5$ such that $\phi(P_i)=P_{\sigma(i)}$ for all $i\in J_5$.

On the other hand, the conjugation $\phi_\sigma$ also maps $P_i$ to $P_{\sigma(i)}$.
Therefore the automorphism $\tau:=\phi\circ\phi_{\sigma^{-1}}$ has the property that
$\tau(P_i)=P_i$ for all $i\in J_5$. Consequently also the normalizers are preserved:
$\tau(N_{A_5}(P_i)=N_{A_5}(P_i)$ for all $i\in J_5$. But those normalizers are conjugates of $A_4$, each the stabilizer of an element of $J_5$. Consider a 3-cycle, such as $\alpha=(234)$. The only two 3-cycles normalizing both $P_1$ and $P_5$ are $\alpha$
and $\alpha^{-1}=(243)$. Therefore we must have $\tau(\alpha)=\alpha$ or
$\tau(\alpha)=\alpha^{-1}$. But, we have
$$\tau(\alpha P_2\alpha^{-1})=\tau(P_3)=P_3$$
as well as
$$\tau(\alpha P_2\alpha^{-1})=\tau(\alpha)P_2\tau(\alpha)^{-1}=P_{\tau(\alpha)(2)}.$$
So we must have $\tau(\alpha)(2)=3$, leaving $\tau(\alpha)=\alpha$ as the only possibility.

It follows that $\tau(\beta)=\beta$ for all 3-cycles $\beta\in A_5$. But the 3-cycles generate $A_5$, so $\tau$ must be the identity mapping. Therefore $\phi=\phi_{\sigma}$. QED.

> It follows that there are 120 injective homomorphisms from $A_5$ to $S_5$ and the trivial constant homomorphism.

Comment: What was going wrong in my argument in the comments above @Jyrki Lahtonen?

Comment: The same argument goes thru for $A_n$, $n\ge7$. The case $n=6$ is a famous exception for $S_6$ when the inner automorphisms form an index two subgroup of the automorphism group. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1049663/11619) for $n\ge7$.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Conjugation by the 2-cycle $(12)\in S_5\setminus A_5$ is also an automorphism of $A_5$, but it is not an inner automorphism of $A_5$.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. I have calculated order of $\text {Inn} (G).$ Right?

Comment: So what's the general way of computing order of $\text {Aut} (G)$? Is there any such?

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1258458/11619). I'm still looking for a duplicate. I looked for one before posting this patchwork, but couldn't find anything really clean. Possibly I should have appealed to that thread instead of looking at those 3-cycles?

Comment: @Dbchatto67 I am not aware of one. I suspect it is difficult in general. Let's wait for an expert.

Comment: Can't we prove the claim without using the Sylow-2-groups?

Comment: Possibly @KushalBhuyan. If you can prove some other way that the obvious conjugates of $A_4$ are the only subgroups isomorphic to $A_4$, and hence $\phi$ must permute them. The reason why I used Sylow 2-subgroups is that, as a set, they are characteristic to the group $A_5$, and hence **any** automorphism must permute them.