# If $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$, and $K$ a normal subgroup of $G$, is $H\cap K$ a normal subgroup of $G$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$. I can prove that if $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $H\cap K$ is a normal subgroup of $H$.

My question is whether $H\cap K$ a normal subgroup of $G$? If it is not, can we give a **non-trivial** counterexample?

What if for an arbitrary subgroup $J$, my guess is that $H\cap J $ may not be normal, but I am struggling to give a counterexample.

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Trivially $G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, so if you think it through, the answer should be obvious.

Comment: Exactly what I was typing. +1

Comment: @hardmath yes you're right, but can we have a non-trivial counterexample? I am not quite satisfied with the trivial one. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, we can.  Do you know that the only nontrivial normal subgroup of $S_5$ is $A_5$?

Comment: Get out of my head! :)

Answer (score 5):

What if $G$ is a group and $K=G$ and $H$ is any subgroup which is not normal in $G$?

Edit: The OP wanted a non-trivial example.  It is known that $A_n$ (the collection of even permutations) is the only proper normal subgroup of $S_n$ for $n\geq 5$.  See [Proving that $A_n$ is the only proper nontrivial normal subgroup of $S_n$, $n\geq 5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159994/proving-that-a-n-is-the-only-proper-nontrivial-normal-subgroup-of-s-n-n-ge)

Thus you can simply choose any proper subgroup $H$ of $A_n$ and it will not be normal in $G=S_n$ when you intersect it with $A_n=K$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $D_8$ which is Dihedral group of order 8. Then $<s>$ is subgroup of $D_8$ and $<s,sr^2>$ is a normal subgroup of $D_8$ (because, $|<s,sr^2>| = 4$). Now, $<s> \cap <s,sr^2> = <s>$ is a normal subgroup of $<s,sr^2>$ (because, $|<s>|=2$), BUT $<s>$ is not a normal subgroup of $D_8$.

For, let $s \in <s>$ and $r^3 \in D_8$. Then $r^3s(r^3)^{-1}=r^3sr=rrrsr=rrs(r^{-1})r=rrs=rs(r^{-1})=s(r^{-1})(r^{-1})=sr^2 \notin <s>$.

Now, counter example for your other argument about J:

Consider $G=S_4$, $H=\{e,(1 2)\}$ and $J=S_3$ on the symbols $1$,$2$,$3$. Then both $H$ and $J$ are subgroups of $G$ and none of them is a normal subgroup of $G$. Also note that $H \cap J = H$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G_0$ be any group with non-normal subgroup $H_0$. Let $H=H_0\times G_0$, $G=G_0\times G_0$, and $K=G_0\times\{1\}$